# Forming json with nested objects using STUFF function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I query related tables into json in tsql procedure?
I'm trying to use STUFF function.
I need to output such json:

```
{
  "Id": "4E7ECBE6-3EF6-4F14-B117-C39FCAC00DD5",
  "tasks": [
  {
      "taskOrders": [
        {
          "merchantId": "EFEDE945-3A17-487B-919B-406C9DA8B8A9",
          "merchantOrderNumber": "1129"
        }
      ],
      "totalWeight": 3,
      "state": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

am trying to use such query for "tasks" section and them concat it with upper fields:

```
select '"tasks":[' + STUFF((
        select ',{
          "taskOrders": [
            '+STUFF((
                select ',{
                      "merchantId": "' + cast(o.merchantId as nvarchar(max)) + '",
                      "merchantOrderNumber": "' + cast(o.orderNumber as nvarchar(max)) + '"
                    }'
                from dbo.Order o
                where o.orderNumber = chk.orderNumber
                for xml path(''), type
            ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')+'
          ],
          "totalWeight": ' + cast(chk.weight as nvarchar(max)) + ',
          "state": ' + cast(chk.state as nvarchar(max)) + '"
        }'
        from dbo.Checkpoints as chk
        for xml path(''), type
    ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') + ']'
```

i guess i'm doing something wrong as the output looks like this:

```
"tasks":[{
"taskOrders": [     {
"merchantId": "EFEDE945-3A17-487B-919B-406C9DA8B8A9",
"merchantOrderNumber": "111"
 }
],
"totalWeight": 1,
"state": 1
 }
],
"totalWeight": 1,
"state": 1
}]
```

should I use cursors or it's possible to accomplish it by STUFF?

Comment: Why not use [`FOR JSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: As an aside, `STUFF()` is just removing the leading comma, it has nothing to do with the string aggregation. See [this post](https://sqlperformance.com/2022/02/t-sql-queries/string-aggregation-over-the-years-in-sql-server) for some background and `FOR XML PATH` and why you should use `STRING_AGG` if you are on a modern version (if `FOR JSON` doesn't work out).

Comment: thank you, didn't know about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server 2016 and later have [built-in support for JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server). Instead of using `STUFF` and `FOR XML` here try using `FOR JSON PATH` instead, e.g.:

```sql
/*
 * Example data...
 */
create table dbo.[Order] (
  merchantId uniqueidentifier,
  orderNumber varchar(10)
);
insert dbo.[Order] (merchantId, orderNumber) values
  ('EFEDE945-3A17-487B-919B-406C9DA8B8A9', '1129'),
  ('d79ce36c-5721-414b-a050-0a9105defe67', '1129');
  
create table dbo.Checkpoints (
  Id uniqueidentifier,
  orderNumber varchar(10),
  state int,
  weight int
);
insert dbo.Checkpoints (Id, orderNumber, state, weight) values
  ('4E7ECBE6-3EF6-4F14-B117-C39FCAC00DD5', '1129', 1, 1);

/*
 * Example query..
 */
select
  chk.Id,
  json_query((
    select
      o.merchantId,
      o.orderNumber as merchantOrderNumber
    from dbo.[Order] o
    where o.orderNumber = chk.orderNumber
    for json path
  ), '$') as tasks,
  weight as totalWeight,
  state
from dbo.Checkpoints chk
for json path, without_array_wrapper;
```

Which yields the output:

```json
{
    "Id": "4E7ECBE6-3EF6-4F14-B117-C39FCAC00DD5",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "merchantId": "EFEDE945-3A17-487B-919B-406C9DA8B8A9",
            "merchantOrderNumber": "1129"
        },
        {
            "merchantId": "D79CE36C-5721-414B-A050-0A9105DEFE67",
            "merchantOrderNumber": "1129"
        }
    ],
    "totalWeight": 1,
    "state": 1
}
```

Comment: Just a nit, `STUFF()` isn't doing any of the actual work here, it just removes the leading comma. Technically it should be `instead of using FOR XML PATH`/